# Maximo - webapp cannot be launched from browser again if not signed out properly, must close browser and restart?

Tags: internet-explorer, session, web-applications, maximo

All users are experiencing a weird behavior: after logging in, if they close the tab of Maximo webapp without actually SIGNING OUT, and if they input the login page address into the address bar again, the browser only will give a white screen -- the connection seems to be there, but the content won't show.

The way to work around is if they forgot to click signing out, they have to close the browser all together then reopen the browser, but this annoyance disrupt other tasks that use the browser. Is this because the JSP session is still stored in the browser? Is there any way to handle this so that a user can close the tab whenever they want to and reopen the webapp at ease, even if they forget to properly sign out?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Maximo are you using? Are you using third party LDAP or using maximo to authenticate? What version weblogic or websphere are you using? In latest maximo 7.5.0.5 if you use

`http://maximo.com:9080/maximo/ui/` from an active session it should return you back.

Comment: Hi, I am using Maximo 5.2 and Weblogic 7.0.

Comment: Even up to Maximo 7.5.0.4 there were issues with the jsessionid cookie remaining. They did some work in 7.5.0.5 to address this, so I imagine its possible that wonky login code exists in 5.2 ... Although they made the transition from client/server to web based app, I don't think they've refined the login code to work reliably in different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

When you sign out a row is removed from the `MAXSESSION` table as part of the processing. When you close the browser without a sign out, the row in `MAXSESSION` is not removed. That simple.

You have to wait for Maximo to clear out you old `MAXSESSION` before you can log in again. Nothing to do with the App Server or `LDAP`.